# dkms does not automatically rebuild after kernel upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, dkms

as mentioned in the title all DKMS modules installed on my system won't be automatically rebuilt after a kernel upgrade.

```
# ls -la /var/lib/dkms/
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4.0K May 26 11:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 86 root root 4.0K May 25 19:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K May 25 18:56 anbox-modules-ashmem
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K May 25 18:57 anbox-modules-binder
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May  2 18:34 bbswitch
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    6 Jul  8  2008 dkms_dbversion
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 26 11:55 nvidia-381
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 26 11:55 virtualbox
```

I always have to rebuild it manually after a kernel upgrade.
If there are any logs or configs needed to diagnose this problem I will supply them as soon as possible.

System information:

```
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon User Edition 5.9
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

# apt list dkms -a
Listing... Done
dkms/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3 all [installed]
dkms/xenial,xenial 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11 all
```

EDIT 1:

Removal of linux-image-4.8.0-52 log: https://pastebin.com/a0L6fbFj

Installation of linux-image-4.8.0-52 log: (N/A)

EDIT 2:

`dkms status`:

```
# dkms status
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.

# cd /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-381/381.22/build

# ls -la dkms.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,2K Mai 26 11:54 dkms.conf

# dkms status
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
```

`ls -la /usr/src`:

```
# ls -la /usr/src/
total 44K
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4,0K Mai 26 16:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4,0K Apr 25 19:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4,0K Apr 22 14:20 bbswitch-0.8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4,0K Apr 29 18:50 gmock
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K Apr 29 18:50 gtest
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4,0K Mai 16 18:39 linux-headers-4.4.0-78
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4,0K Mai 16 18:39 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4,0K Mai 25 19:42 linux-headers-4.8.0-53
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4,0K Mai 25 19:42 linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4,0K Mai 20 16:43 nvidia-381-381.22
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4,0K Mai 11 16:31 virtualbox-5.0.40
```

`ls /usr/src/*/dkms.conf`:

```
# ls /usr/src/*/dkms.conf
/usr/src/bbswitch-0.8/dkms.conf  /usr/src/nvidia-381-381.22/dkms.conf /usr/src/virtualbox-5.0.40/dkms.conf
```

Comment: Could you add a full log of a kernel install or remove?

Comment: @user.dz I added a log for removal and installation

Comment: Anwar those are "detected" filetypes by hastebin.

Comment: Some of your packages does not have a dkms.conf file. What are the "anbox" modules?

Comment: https://anbox.io from here

Comment: Please show me the `terminal` output of `dkms status` and `ls -al /usr/src`.

Comment: @heynnema added to post

Comment: Thanks! Now please show me `ls /usr/src/*/dkms.conf`. How did you add these directories to /var/lib/dkms? Did you do a dkms add, dkms build, and dkms install?

Comment: @heynnema added! I did not touch anything in `/var/lib/dkms`. I guess it was automatic

Comment: Thanks! How did you add the files to /usr/src? At any point did you do a `dkms add` or `dkms build` or `dkms install`? gmock and gtest are not dkms modules. Assuming that you have the original source files for those, delete those two directories from /usr/src , then show me the result of `dkms status` again.

Comment: Also need to see `ls -alR /var/lib/dkms/anbox*`

Comment: @heynnema I moved gtest and gmock out of the directories (into /root) but I still get the error, that a dkms.conf could not be found. I never added anything manually. I installed the packages and they installed themselves to /usr/src (and probably to /var/lib/dkms). 
`ls -alR /var/lib/dkms/anbox*` https://hastebin.com/raw/iyucejajal

Comment: Now move/delete the `/var/lib/dkms/anbox*` directories out of `/var/lib/dkms` as there's no accompanying source directories in `/usr/src`, and then show me `dkms status` again. There should be no errors now for that command.

Comment: After moving the anbox modules out of the folder (btw. I uninstalled anbox some days ago) `dkms status` shows, that all modules are installed (where virtualbox and nvidia module have been installed by me) https://hastebin.com/raw/edirogotul

Comment: Good! Progress! Lastly show me the output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*`. After seeing that, I'll put together an answer that you can review and then vote/accept if it was helpful.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/raw/amovofoxat Sorry for the German language, could not change it with `LANG`/`LANGUAGE`/`LC_ALL`

Comment: Looks good. Give me a few minutes and I'll put together an answer for you. What is/was the gtest/gmock software?

Comment: @heynnema I don't really know :D. If you search for it it says, that it is a testing framework for c++ applications called Google Mock / Google Test

Comment: @Scrumplex have the bbswitch, nividia, and virtualbox dkms software modules been behaving themselves since we fixed dkms up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the comments...

There were multiple problems to solve.

- we removed the `/usr/src/gmock` and `/usr/src/gtest` as they weren't dkms software modules. If you need this software for some reason, either reinstall it, or create `~/src` and put the gmock/gtest software there, and do the appropriate `make` commands (or whatever) to build that software.
- we removed the `/var/lib/dkms/anbox*` directories as they were missing their associated `/usr/src/anbox*` source code due to an incomplete uninstall, and caused the `dkms status` command to fail, looking for a `dkms.conf` file that didn't exist.
- the `dkms status` now correctly shows the `installed` status of bbswitch, nividia, and virtualbox dkms softwares.
- future kernel upgrades should properly build/rebuild the remaining bbsswitch, nividia, and virtualbox dkms software modules.
- we also checked that the virtualbox-dkms was the correct version for the installed virtualbox.

Comment: Good work! "***future kernel upgrades should properly...***": As there have been a few automatic kernel updates since the answer was posted can you ping the user to see if everything is indeed working? Then ping me to upvote please :)

Comment: Everything works how it should. :D

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I contacted the user, and as you can see, it's still working fine... so I've come to collect my +1 :-)

Comment: @heynnema. Thanks... paid in full... and you'll pass me in points soon :)